# Magento2 : Can I call same plugin multiple time?

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout

I have used plugin in one extension

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
    <plugin name="Amasty_Checkout::DefaultConfigProvider" type="Amasty\Checkout\Plugin\DefaultConfigProvider" />
</type>

public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, $config)
    {
        if (!in_array('amasty_checkout', $this->layout->getUpdate()->getHandles()))
            return $config;

        $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();

        foreach ($config['quoteItemData'] as &$item) {
            $additionalConfig = $this->itemHelper->getItemOptionsConfig($quote, $item['item_id']);

            if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled(self::AMASTY_STOCKSTATUS_MODULE_NAMESPACE)) {
                $item['amstockstatus'] = $this->itemHelper->getItemCustomStockStatus($quote, $item['item_id']);
            }

            if (!empty($additionalConfig)) {
                $item['amcheckout'] = $additionalConfig;
            }
        }

        return $config;
    }
```

Now I want to show attribute and add url to product in checkout sidebar http://prntscr.com/jape88
for that i have to use

```
public function afterGetConfig(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject,
        array $result
    ) {
        $items = $result['totalsData']['items'];
        foreach ($items as $index => $item) {
            $quoteItem = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItemById($item['item_id']);
            $result['quoteItemData'][$index]['manufacturer'] = $quoteItem->getProduct()->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

How can I merge second one with first? Or should I create saperate module for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right approach would be creating separate module for the second plugin, you can use **sortOrder** property to fit concrete execution order with your needings

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

> **Prioritizing plugins**
>
> The sortOrder property for plugins determine when their before, after, or around methods get called when more than one plugins are observing the same method.